# Is it proper to use "would" here?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'd like to say something like: I'm going to change the code in the future, according to this requirement.

Here is my version:

```
This code would need to be modified to satisfy this requirement...
```

I don't know if it is proper to use "would" here(or "will"?), or any better expressions?

Answer (score 5):

"Would" suggests conditions necessary for a state to occur or an action to be performed.

> This code would need to be modified given this requirement.

"Will" may be used in the same manner. *(acknowledgment to Barrie England for this point)*

> This code will need to be modified given this requirement.

"Will" is also used to express a determined future outcome.

> This code will have to be modified to satisfy upcoming requirements.

Comment: +1 - as a coder I'd prefer the "would" version as it signals that the requirement may not be accepted/ justified/ cost effective.  In CICS development we'd often flag code as "NREL"ed - "Next RELease" when someone is changing the code for other reasons then do this change while you're there.

Answer (score 4):

"Would" implies that the requirement is in flux, ie. You would use "would" only so long as you are discussing whether to place the requirement. 
Eg.

> If we were to place this requirement, the code would need to change

or

> Given this requirement, the code needs to change

Answer (score 2):

"Would" seems needless here. For me I will say:

> This code needs to be modified to satisfy this requirement...

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine if what you mean is *This code would need to be modified if we wanted to satisfy this requirement.*

If there is a greater probability that those concerned will want to satisfy the requirement, it would be more appropriate to write *This code will need to be modified to satisfy this requirement*, which is another way of saying *This code will need to be modified if we want to satisfy this requirement.*